# Text suggestion, word flow not working

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-920, keyboard, wordflow, lumia-cyan-update

Neither text suggestion nor Word Flow is working on my Nokia Lumia 920. I just got my phone updated with Lumia Cyan.

How can I get those features to work?

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? Word Flow isn't available for all layouts. Also, go to settings -> keyboard, tap on your keyboard layout and make sure the "Type as I flick through letters" option is enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It worked after changing the language from ENGLISH(US).

Comment: Are you on WP 8.1? These feature is not dependent on Lumia Cyan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Word Flow and text suggestions aren't available with all languages. To see if your current language is supported, see [Windows Phone feature and service availability](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/How-to/wp8/basics/feature-and-service-availability).

If your language is in the list, go to Settings → Keyboard, tap on your language and make sure that the "Suggest text" and "Type as I flick through letters" options are enabled.

For more information on using the on-screen keyboard, see [Windows Phone typing shortcuts](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/How-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/typing-shortcuts).

Comment: I changed the language to ENG(us) and then it worked. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider [upvoting](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and/or [accepting](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer, for the benefit of others who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on googling.

http://intertechie.blogspot.in/2014/12/solution-for-wordflow-keyboard-not.html

Just long press your language and change it and retry.

Editing after the comment for proper answer.

In windows keyboard, there is a button, to change your language. Long press the button, 3-4 languages will pop-up depending on number of language keyboards you installed. Change it to your geo-location and try, the keyboard will work. If it is just English, then changing from EN-US to EN-UK will work or vice versa.